# Openfeint offline config file

Tags: iphone, openfeint

I have downloaded my offline config file for my openfeint game.

I added it to my project but still get a message that this does not have offline support.

Where does the config file go in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Iphone, after compiling your project,
In the xcode project you open new group(folder).
Put the .xml offline file you downloaded from OpenFeint.
And hit run & build.

It worked for me. :)